# what is the real DC power dissipated by an inductor that is pulsed on off

Tags: mosfet, switching, thermal

A meter indicates a higher DC power being delivered to a circuit consisting of an inductor switched on and off by a MOSFET on both the high and low side, than the heat measured by a thermistor. The thermistor test indicates only a small fraction of the input power is actually dissipated by the inductor. This makes it appear that the power is going somewhere else. For this test, the coil is the only load. Current and voltage measurements were taken with both digital and analog meters to reduce possibilities of error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to perform an exact caloric measurement of dissipated thermal power on an inductor. But I have to assume you did the necessary prerequisites.

Besides this there are some possibilites for errors.

- Electromagnetical power can be radiated during switch on/off. The percentage depends on duty cycle, inductance, dimensions of coil and frequency of switching. However EM radiation should not show up in DC power if measured properly. But meters with poor quality will deliver tainted results.
- If other metal parts are around you may induce eddy currents which maybe deliver the thermal power outside your caloric chamber. Depending on the ferromagnetic properties of those materials they may lead to (virtual) DC components in your measurements especially with odd duty cycles
- If your inductor is soldered somewhere you may encounter the Peltier effect. So DC power is converted to thermic transport power (reduction of local enthropy) instead of thermal power.
- The leads to your caloric chamber may dissipate substantial thermal power, not only by ohmic heating but also by thermal conduction.

Answer (score 0):

The small amount of heat dissipated by the inductor is due to its \$I^2R\$ losses and quite possibly some core losses (eddy current and saturation).

The rest of the power loss comes from the fact that the inductor is storing energy in one half cycle and that energy is being disposed of in the next half cycle. The disposal of energy is likely to be in the MOSFET that shorts out the inductor.

To get more details please state what MOSFETs are being used and what frequency you are operating at. Please also note that measurement by a thermistor might likely give big errors due to heat being taken away by convection currents.

Comment: I have researched this further, and have found that there is actually very little DC power dissipated..mostly from the I^2 R losses in the windings. The larger portion..(85-95%) is stored in the magnetic field. So, I have placed a secondary winding over the primary. Now I can measure the coil power dissipated in an external, secondary load resistor. This solves the question...where does the power go?

Comment: So, does that energy, each cycle, get turned to heat in one of the mosfets as I suspect?

Comment: There is a division between energy and power; only power can be dissipated as heat. The current through the coil resistance, and the mosfet ON resistance is the only source of heat. The total resistance there in milli-Ohms,..very little heat produced.

Comment: Energy per cycle is power because a cycle is time and energy per (divided by) cycle time exactly equals power. So putting that to one side, how do you explain what happens to the energy stored in the inductor? It seems perfectly feasible and clear to me.